How to output executing code from a cpu debugging program?
I'm looking for a way to dump the actual code running through a cpu during a given execution cycle.
Am guessing the most rudimentary version would capture the Linux boot process, and shutdown process.  The output would be able to be "compiled" and run on its own.
The second step would be to run a given application and capture these instructions and data parts.
The third step would be to replay these items separating the data from the instructions, allowing for new data to be substituted.
Anyone understand or have ideas?
No try.  Inquiry.  Ideas?
